# How To Apply New UV Edit to Model

Tags: materials, uv, image, uv-image-editor

So I'm UV Editing when suddenly I discovered that the edits I was making weren't applying to the model in the Layout tab. I was confused and went back to the UV Editing tab and discovered that the edits were being made there. Why is that? Do I have to apply somehow to the material?[image]

Here is the image of the Layout tab
[image]

Here is the image of the UV Editing tab (what I want to appear in the Layout tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to apply the texture. To do this in the Shader Editor add an Image Texture Node and a UV Map node. And then it will apply your mapped texture.

The set up looks like this.

[image]

Comment: I hope that helps, it took me a long time to get my head around UV mapping, and how everything interacts. Especially using multiple maps on an object and assigning vertex groups etc. I can elaborate further and edit my answer if you still don't understand. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still trying to wrap my head around this and this will really help in the future!